# SQL - using SELECT Alias in WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias

I am having a heck of a time getting this query to work. Basically I need to do a CASE statement to get the person's NickName if they have one, otherwise use their FirstName. Then in the WHERE statement, do a LIKE statement on that above CASE statement.

I've been able to get it to work if I **only** do the FirstName/NickName but when I add in other columns it stops working.

Here is what I've got

```
SELECT
    LastName
  , Company
  , Status
  , CASE
      WHEN NickName = '' THEN FirstName
      WHEN NickName IS NULL THEN FirstName
      ELSE NickName
    END AS FName
FROM database
WHERE
       Status = 'Active'
  AND  Company = '@Company'
  AND  FName + ' ' + LastName LIKE '%@search%'
  OR   LastName + ', ' + FName LIKE '%@search%'
```

Obviously the above doesn't work because I'm trying to use an alias in my WHERE clause. I get

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Invalid column name 'FName'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Invalid column name 'FName'.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: SQL Server. The answer below got me working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Common Table Expression or Subquery to create the FName as a kind of virtual column of a new resultset.  You can that use the resultset as a kind of virtual table and filter on that in the where clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    LastName
    , Company
    , Status
    , CASE
        WHEN NickName IS NULL OR NickName = '' THEN FirstName
        ELSE NickName
      END AS FName
  FROM database
  WHERE Status = 'Active'
  AND  Company = '@Company'
) FNames
WHERE FName + ' ' + LastName LIKE '%@search%'
   OR LastName + ', ' + FName LIKE '%@search%'
```

Comment: Works perfect! I tried something just like this but I wasn't SELECTING * from the sub query. Makes all the difference :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `CROSS APPLY` to create an alias

```
SELECT LastName
     , Company
     , Status
     , FName
FROM database
     CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT CASE WHEN NickName = '' THEN FirstName
                     WHEN NickName IS NULL THEN FirstName
                     ELSE NickName
                END AS FName
     ) AS CA1
WHERE Status = 'Active'
      AND  Company = '@Company'
      AND  FName + ' ' + LastName LIKE '%@search%'
      OR   LastName + ', ' + FName LIKE '%@search%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without the CASE statement

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        LastName
      , Company
      , Status
      , ISNULL(NULLIF(NickName, ''), FirstName) AS FName
    FROM database
    WHERE Status = 'Active'
      AND Company = '@Company') data
WHERE (FName + ' ' + LastName LIKE '%' + @search + '%')
   OR (LastName + ', ' + FName LIKE '%' + @search + '%')
```

Comment: I didn't test this, but I don't think it would work since you're using your Alias (FName) in the WHERE clause. That isn't allowed, hence the original cause of the post

Comment: At least try it before you knock it. I'm using the alias of a sub query. Your original post was not using a sub query. Using the alias of a sub query is perfectly valid sql

Comment: B.t.w. The post you accepted as the answer also uses the alias in the where clause...

Comment: My apologies. I should have read through it more. You are correct and this does work as expected.